# Reg expression: why "name" not returned as a match

Tags: ruby, regex

The following regular expression returns "Gray" and "James" as matches. I don't understand why "Name" isn't a match. Can you explain?

```
"Name:  Gray, James"[/(\w+), (\w+)/]
```

Comment: because your regular expression matches two words separated by a comma and a space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an explanation how your regex worked

```
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\w+)»
   Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the characters “, ” literally «, »
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(\w+)»
   Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
```

Gray, James 
(\w+), (\w+)

`Name` does not follow comma.

Comment: thanks, where did you get that explanation. It looks like it was generated by a program.

Answer (score 0):

match a word next to a comma no spaces "(\w+),"

match a word after a comma and a space ", (\w+)"